# How To Create Razor MVC That Accesses Data from a Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, razor

New to MVC, I am trying to get a model-view-component that works. The only constraints are that the data gets populated by a stored proc in a C# class, and that the PartialView uses Razor and is stored in the _Shared folder so all pages can reference it.

All I have that I think might work is the ViewModel, BreadcrumbViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Web.Controllers.ViewModels
{
  public class BreadcrumbViewModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int InverseDepth { get; set; }
  }

  public class BreadcrumbsViewModel
  {
    public List<BreadcrumbViewModel> getBreadcrumbModel(string thisURL)
    {
        //thisURL contains the path of the current page, so the stored proc can find its parents.
        List<BreadcrumbViewModel> listBVM = new List<BreadcrumbViewModel>();
        BreadcrumbViewModel model;
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "getBreadcrumb";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@thisURL", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                cmd.Parameters["@thisURL"].Value = thisURL;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        model = new BreadcrumbViewModel
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                            ParentId = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]),
                            Label = reader[2].ToString(),
                            URL = reader[3].ToString(),
                            SortOrder = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]),
                            InverseDepth = Convert.ToInt32(reader[5])
                        };
                        listBVM.Add(model);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (listBVM == null)
        {
            model = new BreadcrumbViewModel
            {
                Id = 1,
                ParentId = 0,
                Label = "Home",
                URL = "/",
                SortOrder = 1,
                InverseDepth = 1
            };
            listBVM.Add(model);
        }
        return listBVM;
    }
  }
}
```

If this ViewModel is correct, what would the Controller and PartialView that references the List<> look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewmodels should not be used for accessing data directly. Your controller should fetch the data for the viewmodel and even the controller should be relying on some data access classes.

Viewmodels generally consists of properties that hold data fields. They should not have any behavior and they should not access to a database most of all.

I would start by isolating data access to another class.

```
public class BreadcrumbProvider
{
    public List<BreadcrumbViewModel> getBreadcrumbModel(string thisURL)
    {
        //your method
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ListBreadcrump(string url)//you can also define a model here
{
    var model = new BreadcrumbProvider().getBreadcrumbModel(url);
    return View(model);
}
```

Then you can use the list as model in your view.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<BreadcrumbViewModel>
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me a little further along. I added @using Web.Controllers in the .cshtml file, and was able to get the SDK to accept [at]model System.Collections.Generic.List<BreadcrumbViewModel> . How do I traverse the list using a [at]foreach loop? It doesn't like [at]foreach (var breadcrumb in Breadcrumbs){...}

Comment: I tried that as well, but breadcrumb does not expose the field properties for the list, only the getBreadcrumbModel.

Comment: @ShoreShotWeb Are you sure you are using the BreadcrumbViewModel in your view? Not the BreadcrumbsViewModel.

Comment: model System.Collections.Generic.List<BreadcrumbViewModel>
[at]foreach (var breadcrumb in Model)
{
    <a href="[at]Html.DisplayFor(anchor => breadcrumb.URL)">...</a>
}
It doesn't like breadcrumb.URL. The only intellisense options I get are Equals, getBreadcrumbs, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString.

Comment: @ShoreShotWeb Use href=@breadcrumb.URL instead of Html.DisplayFor(), it works on the model instance, not your loop variable.

Comment: The SDK liked that syntax much better. Just getting a runtime error on the foreach, "nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code". It most likely returning a null set to the Model. As soon as I get that fixed, I will send an update with the complete code solution. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Partial turned out like:
[at]using Web.Controllers
[at]{int i = 0;}
<div class="header_left">
[at]{
    [at]model System.Collections.Generic.List<Breadcrumb>
    var ctrlBC = new Breadcrumbs();
    var thisPath = Request.RawUrl;
    var listBC = ctrlBC.getPageBreadcrumbs(thisPath);
    foreach (var breadcrumb in listBC)
    {
        if (i != 0) 
        {   
            [at]: &gt; 
        }
        else
        {
            i = 1;
        }
        <a href=[at]breadcrumb.URL>[at]breadcrumb.Label</a>
    }
}
</div>